# C# - Call C++ DLL function whit ref

Tags: c#, c, struct, marshalling, dllimport

I am trying to call a DLL function in C++ from my C# code.

**DLL function code and struct (C++):**

```
typedef struct{
    Operacion RespuestaOperacion; 
    char var1[256];           
    int var2;                      
    char var3[33];                    
    char var4[1025];                 
    char var5[20];                       
    char var6[11];                  
    char var7[7];                      
} TResultado;
```

`typedef void (WINAPI *TPROC_PAY_VENTA)(long Importe, bool ProcessMessages, TResultado *Resultado);`

**My C# code:**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TResultado
{
    public Operacion RespuestaOperacion;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string var1;
    public int var2;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33)]
    public string var3;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 1025)]
    public string var4;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
    public string var5;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 11)]
    public string var6;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 7)]
    public string var7;   
}

[DllImport("DLLName.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void Pay_Venta(long importe, bool ProcessMessages, ref TResultado Resultado);

TResultado Resultado = new TResultado();
long cent = 1;

CRPayIUN_Venta(cent, true, ref Resultado);
```

**ERROR!!!**

The problem I am having is that when passing through the function it tells me:

*Additional information: Attempt to read or write in the protected memory. This often indicates that there is other memory corrupted.*

**What am I doing wrong??**
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your title says `C++`, but your question and tags say `c`.  Which is it?

Comment: You may not be doing anything wrong.  If there is a bug inside the dll which accesses memory outside the application assigned memory you could get the exception.

Comment: `long` is 32-bit, so `int` in C#

Comment: Sorry  Amy , is a C++. I edit.

Comment: I have traded long for int and change "CallingConvention.Cdecl" for "CallingConvention.Stdcall" and it's work!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl` is a  problem. The C function typedef is:

`typedef void (WINAPI *TPROC_PAY_VENTA)(long Importe, bool ProcessMessages, TResultado *Resultado);`

`WINAPI` means `stdcall`. Change the calling convention on the `DllImport` line to `CallingConvention.Stdcall`.

It definitely makes sense that a memory violation error occurs here; if the C# code thinks the calling convention is `cdecl` it will add a few bytes to the stack pointer, which unbalances the stack.

Comment: I change and it's work!!! But I have a new problem. The structure does not receive the data, it mixes it up and I don't know why.

Comment: The memory violation is actually caused by the *long* parameter, must be int in the C# declaration.  In 32-bit mode it causes the pointer to be passed in the wrong stack location.  The last parameter requires [Out] so the struct is copied back after the call.